# Why am I getting a rendering error when adding a tablayout?

Tags: android, dependencies, android-tablayout

I have rebuilt and cleaned my project:

[image: Error message]

My gradle dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Android studio version? did you update it to the latest version?

Comment: android studio 1.5.1  version